# Linear transformation of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the full formulation of the question:

> *Let X~exp(0.1), and define Y=-2X. Find the PDF of Y.*

I solved it with linear transformation of moment generating function:

$$
M_X(t)=\frac{0.1}{0.1-t} \rightarrow M_Y(t)=M_X(-2t)=\frac{0.1}{0.1+2t}=\frac{0.05}{0.05+t} =- \frac{0.05}{-0.05-t}
$$
And I'm told that I'm wrong because exponential function cannot have negative parameter. Why am I wrong if that's what comes out of the moment-generating function? Another way of doing that is this, and I can't understand the difference:
[image: Another way of doing that is this, and I can't understand the difference.]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the exponential distribution you can't have $\lambda$ (the exponential parameter) negative, since then it wouldn't be a distribution. I will demonstrate,

Suppose $X\sim \exp(\lambda)$ for $\lambda<0$, then
$P(\Omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$ but this integral is not finite (but it needed to be $1$) since $\lambda <0 \iff -\lambda > 0$ (look at the power of the exponential).

---

Now $Y$ has a pdf of $f_Y(y)=0.05e^{0.05y}$ but the difference here is that this holds for $y\leq 0$ (and $f_y$ is $0$ everywhere else) and not for $y\geq0$ as is the case with the exponential distribution.

In the picture you've posted the writer takes for granted that you have understood exactly how $F_Y$ is defined (e.g $F_Y(y) = 1$ for $y\geq0$) and then proceeds to differentiate it at $y < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the argument that $M_Y(t) = \frac{-0.05}{-0.05-t}$.

The problem is that you cannot go from here to claiming that "$Y$ has the exponential distribution with rate $-0.05$". The exponential distribution is only defined for a positive rate, so this wouldn't make any sense. For all $\lambda>0$, it is true that when $W \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, we have $M_W(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$, but you're trying to apply it to $\lambda<0$.

We could imagine making the following definition: for $\lambda < 0$, let the $\text{Unexp}(\lambda)$ distribution have support $(-\infty,0]$ and PDF $-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ on that support. (Note the difference in sign from the exponential PDF!) Then we can prove that if $W \sim \text{Unexp}(\lambda)$, we have $M_W(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$. Once that is done, if we encounter a random variable $Y$ with $M_Y(t) = \frac{-0.05}{-0.05-t}$, we can deduce that $Y \sim \text{Unexp}(-0.05)$.

Though $\text{Unexp}(\lambda)$ is close to being a generalization of $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ to cases where $\lambda<0$, there are some reasons why we want to keep it separate. For example, it does not share the minimum-of-two-exponentials property that is one of the big reasons why we care about the exponential distribution.